# shorten url using htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error, url-shortener

I am completely beginner to htaccess, I am trying to shorten my following url..

From

```
 http://website.com/index.php?student-name=john
 http://website.com/index.php?teacher-name=amy
 http://website.com/index.php?class=xxx
```

To

```
 http://website.com/john
 http://website.com/amy
 http://website.com/xxx
```

I have tried following .htaccess code,

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?student-name=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?teacher-name=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?class=$3 [L]
```

but, i shows "500-Internal servor error"....

**EDIT :**

when i am trying to use one rewrite_rule, its works fine. Like

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?student-name=$1 [L]
```

(or)

```
 RewriteRule ^student/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?student-name=$1 [L]
```

when i am trying to use two or more rewrite_rule, its shows "500-Internal servor error". Like

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?student-name=$1 [L]              
RewriteRule ^teacher/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?teacher-name=$1 [L]
```

(or)

```
RewriteRule ^student/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?student-name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^teacher/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?teacher-name=$1 [L]
```

Its shows error log is: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

what's that mean?

Comment: Try getting rid of the `RewriteBase` directive. Are you sure that mod_rewrite is compiled and enabled in your Apache server?

Comment: > but, i didn't seen any change in my url....

did you try opening  http://website.com/xxx ? Was the result a 404 or some other error? What about server logs?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it says "500-Internal Server Error",

Comment: Then look into the logs of your server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. Why? How does Apache know if the string in the first path segment is a student, teacher or class? It doesn't, so it will always rewrite to a student-name.

Instead use urls like:

```
http://example.com/student/john
http://example.com/teacher/amy
http://example.com/class/xxx
```

Now the rewrite is trivial, since each group has a common prefix.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^student/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?student-name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^teacher/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?teacher-name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^class/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?class=$1 [L]
```

As for the 500 internal server error you need to check your Apache error log. Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled, and that you restarted your Apache after you did this. Besides the rules, I changed the lowercase l in `FollowSymLinks` into an uppercase L, but I am unsure if this can cause any problems.

Comment: when i use one rewrite_rule is working. but when i use more than one  rewrite_rule is not working,Lowercase l is also working.

Comment: Please see [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging). Add that to your httpd.conf, then restart Apache. Then check your Apache error log and tell me what the error is you get.

Comment: error-log: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: My rules do not cause that, so I assume you have more rules. Please edit your question and edit in your entire (original) .htaccess file.